# Why does CsvToBeanBuilder struggle mapping boolean csv entries to List<Boolean>?

Tags: java, csv, data-conversion, opencsv

I have method to read CSV class:

```
public void readCSV() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileName = "<path-to-csv>/question.csv";
        List<Question> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new FileReader(fileName))
                .withType(Question.class)
                .withSeparator(';')
                .build()
                .parse();
}
```

Question:

```
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    private String questionNumber;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private String question;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
    private String answer1;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 3)
    private String answer2;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 4)
    private String answer3;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 5)
    private String answer4;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 6)
    private String answer5;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 7)
    private String answer6;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 8)
    private String answer7;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 9)
    private String answer8;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 10)
    private String answer9;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 11)
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Boolean> answers = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

and line of csv question

```
1.1 ; Question? ; 1a ; 2b ; 3c ; 4d ; "" ; "" ; "" ; "" ; "" ; True, False,  False, False
```

Unfortunately logs give me information about incorrect type of list

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: Can't convert value ' True, False,  False, False' to type interface java.util.List
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

### Fix

In your scenario, make use of the annotation [`@CsvBindAndSplitByPosition`](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#annotations_2). For your requirements, it's important to override the annotation parameter `splitOn` to a regular expression that meets your specific *splitting* needs.

Change the mapping for the List to:

```
@ElementCollection
@CsvBindAndSplitByPosition(position = 11, 
                           elementType = Boolean.class, 
                           splitOn = "\\s?,\\s?", 
                           writeDelimiter = ",\\s+")
private List<Boolean> answers = new ArrayList<>();
```

### Important

Your input csv file requires an important change/fix:

```
1.1 ; Question? ; 1a ; 2b ; 3c ; 4d ; "" ; "" ; "" ; "" ; "" ;True, False, False, False
```

**Note**: The whitespace in front of the first boolean element is removed. If this is not removed (and ensured), the parsing will fail as it the split token will evaluate to  `True` which can't be converted to `java.lang.Boolean`.

I tested the above code with OpenCSV 5.6/5.7 under OpenJDK 17.